# Get occurrence if there are no numbers between

Tags: regex

I've got strings like these:

> Boosts ATK of Cerebral characters by 2.75x and chain by 1.5x if HP is below 30% at the start of the turn, boosts ATK of Cerebral characters by 2.5x otherwise

and what I need is something like this:

```
Boosts (their )?ATK.+by 2.75x
```

With this regex I would mark a character as a 2.75x ATK booster. The problem lies when I use this regex (to find 1.5 ATK boosters):

```
Boosts (their )?ATK.+by 1.5x
```

That also matches my string, but it shouldn't. I tried to use negative lookback and negative lookahead, without useful results.

So, how can I reject a match if there is a number between ATK and the number that I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `\D*` pattern instead of `.+` to only match non-digit characters between `ATK` and `1.5`:

```
Boosts (their )?ATK\D*by 1\.5x
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yaLtuo/2)

Note the `.` must be escaped if it denotes a literal period.